# insertion order in batch insert

Tags: sql

When inserting multiple rows using a batch update, is the order of insertion the same as the order given in the `INSERT` query?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the order is not guaranteed.  But this could behave differently for different DBMS's.

Comment: Since any relational database table is an **unordered** bag of data anyway, the insert order - if you can even define it - is pointless -- there **is NO** "inherent", system-given *ordering*. The only way you are **guaranteed** to get the data in the order you want is when you `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how/if you execute the inserts in parallel then the order they actually get inserted may or may not reflect the order of the statement.

More importantly to understand is that the order they come out is entirely dependent on any query against those rows, so it doesn't really matter anyway.